# How to join predictions with input data test in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to join predictions from a model and the input data used by sklearn in Python. The code is

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_mat, y, test_size=test_size)
mdl = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=max_depth, n_estimators=n_estimators, n_jobs=n_jobs)
mdl.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = self.mdl.predict(x_test)
```

The problem is that the format of both variables are different. For the input data y_test {Series}, I have a series like this:

> TS
>
> 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z    375.25
>
> 2018-12-23T00:00:00Z    306.13
>
> 2018-11-13T00:00:00Z    542.74
>
> 2018-12-11T00:00:00Z    556.73

but the prediction y_predict {ndarray} is an array like this:

> [374.35747933 303.1865425  559.07108139 545.67544684]

I want to obtain a dataframe such as:

> TS
>
> 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z    375.25   374.35747933
>
> 2018-12-23T00:00:00Z    306.13   303.1865425
>
> 2018-11-13T00:00:00Z    542.74   559.07108139
>
> 2018-12-11T00:00:00Z    556.73   545.67544684

in order to compare one by one visually and/or plot the input and the prediction at a time.

I'd like to keep the index with the timestamp, but I'm afraid this could be another problem since I have tried the following:

```
dataset = pd.concat([pd.Series(y_predict), y_test], axis=1, ignore_index = True)
```

but the obtained result places one series under the other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'predict': y_predict, 'test': y_test})`?

Comment: does this preserve the index?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang, it's really simple and it works

Comment: Yes @vlizana, the Quang Hoang's solution also preserves the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to preserve the timestamp index you can convert the series to dataframe and add a column:

```
results = y_test.to_frame()
results['prediction'] = y_predict
```

Comment: It works too, I tried similar solutions but I didn't convert it to dataframe, so I felt frustrated. Many thanks